# How to automatically change hyperlink destination in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a function in Excel that will automatically change the hyperlink (hyperlink from a cell on one sheet to cells on another sheet) destination?

For example, if my hyperlink was to a set of cells on a different worksheet, and I moved those cells around on the different worksheet, is there a way for the hyperlink destination to change accordingly to where those cells have been moved?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply record a macro of what you need to do. If you are still not able to achieve what you want, paste the recorded text in the question and give more details.

Comment: How are you moving the cells? What's your hyperlink formula look like?  If you have `=Hyperlink(D1,"Link")` and move (literally selecting `D1` and moving it), the link should update itself automatically to show the new location of that cell.

Comment: I used the hyperlink option in the Insert tab, where you manually enter the cell and sheet reference (e.g. A15:F34 - the hyperlink will take you to these cells and have them all highlighted).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ReplaceHyperlinks()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim xOld As String, xNew As String
xTitleId = "ReplaceHyper"
Set Ws = Application.ActiveSheet
xOld = Application.InputBox("Old text:", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
xNew = Application.InputBox("New text:", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each xHyperlink In Ws.Hyperlinks
    xHyperlink.Address = Replace(xHyperlink.Address, xOld, xNew)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).